# why does this javascript code work differently? Is there any thing that I am missing?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, foreach, addeventlistener

i dont' get why my javascript code works differently despite it looks like same to me. I am a beginner and I tried to figure out what is wrong and I couldn't. In one method which I have commented the code works in a way it should work while in other it looks like the code is broken. It works in way it shouldn't and I couldn't figure out why it is happening.

```js
let smallCups = document.querySelectorAll(".cup-small")
let liters = document.getElementById("liters")
let percentage = document.getElementById("percentage")
let remained = document.getElementById("remained")

// smallCups.forEach(function (cup, idx) {
//   cup.addEventListener("click", function () {
//     highLightCups(idx)
//   })
// })

// function highLightCups(idx) {
//   if (smallCups[idx].classList.contains("full")) {
//     idx--
//   }

//   smallCups.forEach(function (cup, idx2) {
//     if (idx2 <= idx) {
//       cup.classList.add("full")
//     } else {
//       cup.classList.remove("full")
//     }
//   })
// }

smallCups.forEach(function(cup, idx) {
  cup.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (smallCups[idx].classList.contains("full")) {
      idx--
    }
    smallCups.forEach(function(cup, idx2) {
      if (idx2 <= idx) {
        cup.classList.add("full")
      } else {
        cup.classList.remove("full")
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --border-color: #144fc6;
  --fill-color: #6ab3f8;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* 1rem = 10px */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #3494e4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.cup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid var(--border-color);
  color: var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 330px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cup.cup-small {
  height: 95px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.cups {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 280px;
}

.cup.cup-small.full {
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.remained {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.remained span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.remained small {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.percentage {
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  height: 0;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>drink water</h2>
  <h3>goal : 2 liter</h3>

  <div class="cup">
    <div class="remained" id="remainded">
      <span id="liters">1.5l</span>
      <span>remained</span>
    </div>

    <div class="percentage" id="percentage">20%</div>
  </div>

  <p class="text">select how many glasses of water that you have drank</p>

  <div class="cups">
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d48313b36e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: let `cup` become `cup2` just as you did with `idx`: `smallCups.forEach(function(cup2, idx2) {`

Comment: Could be due to variable shadowing

Comment: Could you explain the differences that you see between the 2 versions?

Comment: commented version of the script has 2 separated foreach loops, while the current version has 2 nested foreach loops.

Comment: @GrafiCode not really, the second loop is inside the event handler and therefore not nested. I see the difference is that the second version just replaces the function call with the contents of the `highLightCups` function. That's not what I asked though! I was asking for OP to explain the observed difference in behaviour.

Comment: @phuzi  so the observed difference in behaviour is when i run the commented code and click small glass in UI, it only remove class of the clicked glass (class = 'full') in second click. But with the second code (not commented) when I click small glass, it does remove the class but it keeps removing the class of other glass even when I click in same glass. This behaviour doesn't happen with the commented code.

Comment: @phuzi thanks for answering. Now i understand what is happening. .  Glad you helped.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you 

Comment: @phuzi sure. Accepted the answer but can't upvote because I don't have much reputation 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `idx`.

In the commented version `idx` is passed to the function and is passed by value. A local variable (also called `idx`) is created. Any changes to the value of `idx` are not persisted between clicks.

In your version the variable `idx` is captured in a closure by the event handler . Each time the click handler runs it gets the value of the captured variable `idx` which is being updated by the code. The next time the handler runs it uses the updated value of `idx` and not the original value.

To fix your version you will have to create a copy of `idx` e.g. `let index = idx;` and use the variable `index` inside the click handler to make sure the value of `idx` never changes!

```js
let smallCups = document.querySelectorAll(".cup-small")
let liters = document.getElementById("liters")
let percentage = document.getElementById("percentage")
let remained = document.getElementById("remained")

smallCups.forEach(function(cup, idx) {
  cup.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // use original value of idx but do not update it!
    let index = idx;
    if (smallCups[index].classList.contains("full")) {
      index--
    }
    smallCups.forEach(function(cup, idx2) {
      if (idx2 <= index) {
        cup.classList.add("full")
      } else {
        cup.classList.remove("full")
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --border-color: #144fc6;
  --fill-color: #6ab3f8;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* 1rem = 10px */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #3494e4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.cup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid var(--border-color);
  color: var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 330px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cup.cup-small {
  height: 95px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.cups {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 280px;
}

.cup.cup-small.full {
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.remained {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.remained span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.remained small {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.percentage {
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  height: 0;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>drink water</h2>
  <h3>goal : 2 liter</h3>

  <div class="cup">
    <div class="remained" id="remainded">
      <span id="liters">1.5l</span>
      <span>remained</span>
    </div>

    <div class="percentage" id="percentage">20%</div>
  </div>

  <p class="text">select how many glasses of water that you have drank</p>

  <div class="cups">
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
    <div class="cup cup-small">250ml</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d48313b36e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```